# XMLHttpRequest onload not called

Tags: javascript, post, get, xmlhttprequest

I'm very new in JS.
As far as I understand new instances of `XMLHttpRequest` created in function `createNewGetXHR()` must fire `onload` callback function after request is send. Now it works without firing callback. BUT, if I comment do-while cycle(strings 55 and 63) in `postData()` callback starts working( How can I create new GET requests in a loop, so that I can control the exit from this loop?

```
    <script>
        function sleep(ms) {
            ms += new Date().getTime();
            while (new Date() < ms){}
        }
        function createNewGetXHR(uniqId, server_state) {
            alert("In createNewGetXHR()");
            var url = "http://localhost:8080/api/users?uniqId=" + uniqId;
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.open("GET", url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            xhr.onload = function () {
                alert("Fired onload callback");
                if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        var server_resp = xhr.responseText;

                        alert("server_resp: " + server_resp);
                        if (server_resp !== "-") {
                            server_state.working = false;
                            server_state.response_html = server_resp;
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            return xhr;
        }
        function postData() {
            // Get data from froms
            var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
            var surname = document.getElementById('surname').value;
            var action = document.getElementById('action').value;
            // Make json from data
            var data = JSON.stringify({"action": action, "user": {"name": name, "surname": surname}});
            // Prepare request
            var url = "http://localhost:8080/api/users";
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.open("POST", url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            // Handle server response
            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        alert("Server is working. Please wait for the answer!");

                        var REFRESH_RATE = 2000;
                        var uniqId = xhr.responseText;
                        var server_state = { working: true, response_html: "default" };
                        var reqs_holder = [];

                        // Checking for the server answer every $REFRESH_RATE
                        do { // (1) if comment out it - code start working(once)
                            sleep(REFRESH_RATE);

                            var new_req = createNewGetXHR(uniqId, server_state);

                            reqs_holder.push(new_req);
                            new_req.send();
                            //alert("Send GET");
                        } while (server_state.working); // (2) if comment out it - code start working(once)

                        document.write(result_html);
                    }
                }
            };
            // Make post request
            xhr.send(data);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: `sleep(REFRESH_RATE);` is HORRIBLE, all it does is lock up the browser from doing anything

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, while the code spins inside the loop, callbacks like the `onload` are not executed. Since the exit condition from the loop is set inside the callback, we get an infinite loop. The solution is a tail recursive function that will call itself after a delay if the server still has not processed the request.

```
    <script>
        function sleep(ms) {
            ms += new Date().getTime();
            while (new Date() < ms){}
        }
        function waitForResponse(uniqId, refresh_rate) {
            var url = "http://localhost:8080/api/users?uniqId=" + uniqId;
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.open("GET", url, false);
            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
                    var server_resp = xhr.responseText;

                    if (server_resp === "-") {
                        sleep(refresh_rate);
                        waitForResponse(uniqId, refresh_rate);
                    }
                    else
                        document.write(server_resp);
                }
            };
            xhr.send();
        }
        function postData() {
            /* Get data from froms the forms */
            var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
            var surname = document.getElementById('surname').value;
            var action = document.getElementById('action').value;
            var data = JSON.stringify({"action": action,
                "user": {"name": name, "surname": surname}}); // make json from data

            /* Prepare request */
            var url = "http://localhost:8080/api/users";
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.open("POST", url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            xhr.onload = function () { // handle server response
                if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
                    alert("Server is working. Please wait for the answer!");

                    var REFRESH_RATE = 1000;
                    var uniqId = xhr.responseText;

                    waitForResponse(uniqId, REFRESH_RATE);
                }
            };
            xhr.send(data); // make post request
        }
    </script>
```